# Use Better Jinja together with HTMLHint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jinja2

I've been using [Better Jinja](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml) in a project to get syntax highlighting of Jinja code inside of HTML files. I associated all html files with Better Jinja like this:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "jinja-html"
}
```

Now I wanted to add [HTMLHint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HTMLHint.vscode-htmlhint) to the same project but somehow I get no hints in my HTML files. I added these associations for HTMLHint: (the last one is just a guess on my side since the first two didn't seem to work)

```
"htmlhint.documentSelector": [
    "html",
    "htm",
    "jinja-html"
]
```

But this seems to have no effect. If I switch the file type in the status bar from "Jinja HTML" to "HTML" then HTMLHint starts working but I lose all the Jinja highlighting.

Is there a way to have both extensions working together?